# Integration JS and Java

Tags: java, javascript, integration

I have two systems to integrate: 1)desktop application (Java6) and 2)web-application (HTML,JS). I want first application to share some services to the second one. How could simply I do that ? I want some simple solution.

Thanks!

Comment: the question is rather vague and only generic solutions can be given. You should consider providing more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose them as standards [Web Services](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) or [RESTful web-services](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/)

Answer (score 0):

For an application to serve services, it should start server socket on port and listening on it. Or it should be using webservices. JDK6 comes with WebServices support. May be you can look at it.